# Дубликат primary key почему возникает?

Tags: mysql, индексы

Экспортирую таблицу из БД. Создаю копию её с другим именем но такой же структурой и пустую. Потом делаю в неё импорт первой таблицы. Ошибка:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '451' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Ок, удаляю PRIMARY и AUTO_INCREMENT со столбца id делаю обычный INDEX пробую ещё раз. То же самое. Как так? Ну не может быть дубликата я же только что эту таблицу экспортировал из существующей, там не позволил бы mysql создать дубликат

Comment: 1)  кто-то другой паралельно инсертит
2) id = 0 случайно

Comment: Никто не инсертит, это тестовая таблица. id=0 ну не знаю...

Comment: Дайте больше информации, что за база данных, чем экспортируете-импортируете.

Comment: Я не знаю, что ещё давать, обычная таблица без внешних ключей в MySQL, обычный phpmyadmin где используется импорт, экспорт

Comment: В файлике экспорта ключ 451 искали, точно один раз?

Comment: Да искал, точно только одно совпадение